# ?How to sort with chars and numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have many strings which are represent some objects:

```
tua15
tub15
tuc15
[...]
tuk15
tul15
tua16
tub16
```

"tu" is constant, a,b,c...k,l represent month and last two digits represent year (2015, 2016). When I sort this strings I get:

```
tua15
tua16
tub15
tub16
tuc15
tud15
[...]
```

How to sort this strings by letters with corelation with year number?

Comment: `a,b,c...z represent month` 26 months - what crazy planet you live on? :)

Comment: :) small mistake :) a,b,c...k,l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> data = ['tua15', 'tua16', 'tub15', 'tub16', 'tuc15', 'tud15']
>>> print sorted(data, key=lambda k: int(k[3:]))
['tua15', 'tub15', 'tuc15', 'tud15', 'tua16', 'tub16']
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to your code.